# How to get signature, packagename, version number and version name from .apk file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a requirement in which I want to store apk signature, packagename, version number and version name by reading .apk file using javascript or reactjs.
How can this be achieved.
Thank You

Comment: Wrap it around aapt dump https://gist.github.com/j796160836/6ad39ba143bf038bfde8

Comment: First you need to decide which of the two completely different languages you want to use. One is essentially a toy, designed for writing small pieces of code, and traditionally used and abused by inexperienced programmers.

The other is a scripting language for web browsers.

Comment: I need solution in javascript or reactjs

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would give this a try https://github.com/DeviceFarmer/adbkit-apkreader

I have not used it myself but it seems to be doing exactly what you are looking for.